# How can Play Audio file in loop without any interruption?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to develop a simple iPhone app. I need to play sound within a loop. 
How can Play Audio file in loop without any interruption ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the new AVAudioPlayer class in the 2.2 release:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

It has functionality for looping sounds.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know the iPhone SDK at all, but this should be quick: try making the sound itself looping. That way, you should be able to play it with just a single call, and won't need to worry about timing the repeat properly to restart it at the exact right moment.

For instance, [WAV files](http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/wavefiles.html#plst) have very flexible support for looping, and any decent audio editor should let you set looping points.

Answer (score 0):

The AVAudioPlayer has numberOfLoops property where you can specify the number of times you want the audio to loop.